# Can I use a relative pronoun in this sentence?

Tags: relative-pronouns, relative-clauses

> We have to account for every penny we spend on business trips

"We spend on business trips" is a noun phrase complement of "penny" so can I use relative pronoun to rewrite the sentence as follows:

> We have to account for every penny which we spend on business trips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Long answer:

### Which/Who/Whom/That/Nothing

**Which:** is used to refer to a thing mentioned in the previous clause.
**Who:** is used to refer to a person mentioned in the previous clause and that is the subject of the new clause.
**Whom:** is used to refer to a person mentioned in the previous clause but who isn't the subject of the new clause.
**That:** is used to refer to a thing OR a person mentioned in the previous clause.
**Nothing:** can replace either **which**, **whom** or **that** if it is not the subject of the new clause, and if it is not a non-restrictive clause.

For example, you can replace that/which in:

> We have to account for every penny **that/which** we spend on business trips.
>
> We have to account for every penny we spend on business trips. -> **okay**

But you can't here:

> She healed my hand **which** was hurt.
>
> She healed my hand was hurt -> **wrong**

Because **which** replaces my hand, the subject of the second clause.

### So I can use "that" all the time, since it can both replace a thing and a person?

Almost. Non-restrictive clauses are clauses that are introduced with a comma, and that are an optional addition to the sentence. In these, you can't replace **who/which** with **that**.

For example:

> I bought a new dress, **which** I will be wearing to Jo's party. [non-restrictive]
>
> I bought a new dress, that I will be wearing to Jo's party -> **wrong**
> I bought a new dress, I will be wearing to Jo's party -> **wrong**

But you can turn it into a restrictive clause with the same meaning:

> I was wearing the dress **which** I bought to wear to Jo's party. [restrictive]
>
> I was wearing the dress that I bought to wear to Jo's party -> **okay**
>   I was wearing the dress I bought to wear to Jo's party -> **okay**

For more read: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/that-or-which

Comment: Who pronoun can act as the subject of a relative clause but all other relative pronouns is unable. Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

> We have to account for every penny we spend on business trips

Your sentence has a [defining relative clause](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/relative-clauses-defining-relative-clauses)- **we spend on business trips**. It's defining because it explains which particular pennies you have to account for. Normally, you would attach it using a relative pronoun, but:

> If the relative pronoun is the object of the verb then it can be omitted

In this case the object is **penny**, and it is the object of the verb **spend**. It can therefore be omitted, as in your first sentence.

If you want to include the relative pronoun, that's fine. The appropriate relative pronoun is **that** or **which**:  there is no difference in meaning between these, though **which** tends to be preferred in more formal use.